# How to intgreate Google maps in cordova application?

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, cordova, google-maps

i want to include a google map in my cordova project so I put this url     `<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=places" type="text/javascript"></script>` in my trajet.html.

my trajet.html

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=places" type="text/javascript"></script>

<div id="map_canvas">
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/trajet.js"></script>
```

in my trajet.js this code:

```
function onDeviceReady(){
        var map = new GoogleMap();
        map.initialize();
    }   

$(document).ready(function(){


    this.initialize = function(){
     var map = showMap();
        }

    var showMap = function(){
        var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 4,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33, 151),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        }

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);

        return map;
        }


});
```

but i don't found any result ,the map is not display

please help me ,what's the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1) Get your google map api key** :

[Google developer console](https://console.developers.google.com/)

[doc](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key)

Note:
 Even if you compiling on Android & iOS with phongeap, you have to create a 'browser key', and NOT Android or iOS keys.
[image]

**2) Classic Integration**

From the doc, you have to call a script with the api key, and a callback function (here : 'initMap'):

```
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap"
  type="text/javascript">
</script>
```

From the doc:

```
<body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>
      var map;
      function initMap() {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
          zoom: 8
        });
      }
    </script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap"
    async defer></script>
  </body>
```

**2) For your project**

**trajet.html**

```
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/trajet.js"></script>
```

**trajet.js**

```
function loadScript(callback){
    var script  = document.createElement('script');
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.src  = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key='+YOUR_KEY_HERE+'&callback=showMap';
    document.body.appendChild(script);
    callback();
}

function showMap(){
    var map;
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
        center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
        zoom: 8
    });
  }
}

function onDeviceReady(){
    loadScript(showMap);
}
```

**3) Style**

Don't forget to define a 'width' and a 'height' for your map, and eventually, the good positioning, relatively to your css (position : relative or absolute)

```
#map_canvas{
    width:    100%;
    height:   100%;
}
```

Let us know if there is any trouble!